# Entity Framework, Database First, added foreign key relation, will not refresh/create new navigation property

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

Created entity model from existing database.

Discovered the db was missing a foreign key in a mapping table. The column already exists, but the FK constraint was not explicitly defined in the DB.

Created the FK in the db, expecting the update/refresh to see it and create the corresponding navigation properties.

It did not.

Please advise.

For clarity:

```
Tables:  A   (with key A_Id)
         B   (with key B_Id
         Map_AB   (with prime key  [A_Id, B_id] 
                   and foreign key  [B_id] )
```

note: missing foreign key [A_Id]

Created  the foreign key Map_AB(A_Id) --> A(A_Id).

Did refresh from database in visual studio.

Entity A still does not have a navigation property to B and vice versa, nor do they have navigation property to Map_AB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thought of possible workaround as soon as I posted.

I deleted the mapping table (Map_AB) from the model, then updated, adding that table back in from the database, and it created the navigation properties.

Comment: This is something that you will have to get used to if you continue to use Entity Framework.  Changing almost anything requires deleting and re-adding, updating almost never works.  EF is a horrible, flaky generator of obscure issues..  The real solution to your problem (this one, and all the ones to come) is to not use EF ;)